# dojo 1.8: Apply conditional to the result after query

Tags: dojo

I cannot figure how to apply the condition to the result after the query.
This code was asked before but I wanted to enhance it

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojo/query", "dojo/on", "dijit/form/Select", "dojo/domReady!"], function (parser, ready, query, on, Select) {
ready(function () {
    parser.parse();

    var select_Card = new Select({
        name: 'select_PCBA',
        options: [{
            label: "<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp. . .</b></span>",
            value: "",
            selected: true
        }, {
            label: "<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk7ABC Card</b></span>",
            value: "testdata1970_05"
        }, {
            label: "<span id='inUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk7CBC Card</b></span>",
            value: "testdata1970_10"
        }, {
            label: "<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk10DC Card</b></span>",
            value: "testdata2060_03"
        }, {
            label: "<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk6BC Card</b></span>",
            value: "dbProdigy"
        }, {
            label: "<span id='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk6NBC Card</b></span>",
            value: "dbProdigy_MK6N"
        }, ],
        style: {
            width: '150px'
        }
    }, "select_Card");

    select_Card.startup();


    on(select_Card, 'change', function(newValue)
    {
        if query('#inUse')
        {
            alert('Item selected is '+ newValue);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Please select the only highlighted card');                           
        }
    });
    });
});
```

OR Please see [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/q5LC7/7/) for your convenience.

Or do you have better way?

Please advise 
Thanks

Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fredfortier/q5LC7/11/. A few things were wrong with it. I cleaned-up the "ready" stuff to make it run.

I believe that there are a few issues with the structure of the code that you might want to clean-up. But I did not want to change your code too much so I just made it work. One major thing is that you were using the same ids multiple time. I changed it to class. Also, the query function is not scoped to a closure, it will search through the dom. So your condition in the event handler would never have worked.

Again, I do not think that this code if very polished and could be tackled differently, but here it is working without major changes to what you had:

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojo/query", "dojo/on", "dijit/form/Select", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/domReady!"], function (parser, ready, query, on, Select, array) {

    console.debug('rendering...');
    var select_Card = new Select({
        name: 'select_PCBA',
        options: [{
            label: "<span class='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp. . .</b></span>",
            value: "",
            selected: true
        }, {
            label: "<span class='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk7ABC Card</b></span>",
            value: "testdata1970_05"
        }, {
            label: "<span class='inUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk7CBC Card</b></span>",
            value: "testdata1970_10"
        }, {
            label: "<span class='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk10DC Card</b></span>",
            value: "testdata2060_03"
        }, {
            label: "<span class='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk6BC Card</b></span>",
            value: "dbProdigy"
        }, {
            label: "<span class='NotinUse'><b>&nbsp&nbspMk6NBC Card</b></span>",
            value: "dbProdigy_MK6N"
        }, ],
        style: {
            width: '150px'
        }
    }, "select_Card");

    select_Card.startup();

    on(select_Card, 'change', function(newValue)
    {
        console.debug('got selected value:', newValue, 'from options:', select_Card.options);
        array.forEach(select_Card.options, function(option) {
            if (option.value == newValue) {
                  console.debug('found selected option in the list: ', option);
                  if (option.label.indexOf("'inUse'") != -1) {
                        alert('Item selected is '+ newValue)
                  } else {
                        alert('Please select the only highlighted card');
                  }
            }
        });
    });
```

});

Comment: Hi Frederic, That is a quick help. I begin to understand better and I learned from your way of doing that ie debugging. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, a debugger like Firebug will help you understand the structure of objects and DOM elements if you are just starting with Dojo or other DOM manipulation toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your code doesnt even run, your on() function is all messy, just pasting it in de editor showed errors.
second, using multiple id's that are exactly the same is a very very bad idea, use classes instead.

```
on(select_Card, 'change', function(newValue)
{
  var display = this.get('displayedValue');
  if(display.indexOf("class='inUse'") !== -1 || newValue === 'testdata1970_10'){
    alert('correct stuff')
  }else{
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73F2t/

here is a corrected fiddle, the or clause means you can use either condition for filtering and it should work

Comment: Hi  Richcardo... Thanks for your advice